# Easy way to kill all links

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is there an easy method to kill all links on a Wordpress page? I'm basically stripping down the twenty-eleven theme and pulling it in a simple iFrame on my site to act as a simple news feed. I want to kill all the links, eg - currently, by default, the Wordpress Post titles link to the stand alone posts; just wondering if there's a simple way to void those links with a CSS snippet I can throw in the header, or style sheet.

**Edit:** To be specific, I want to keep the text of those default links. Just not have them link, so I think `display: none;` wouldn't work.

*I know I could do it manually, just always on the lookout for little tricks - as I feel there could be one, since I don't want any active links on the page.*

Comment: just edit the relevant pages, and remove them its not more difficult than going about a js / css way. I would actually recommend getting a basic theme and going from there, not twentyeleven as its pretty loaded with CSS (mobiles / etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess jQuery could do that for you with something like:

```
$('a').removeAttr('href');
```

Comment: Yup this would work. The side-effect is that all the navigation goes with it. You may need to scope the selector to only affect the content area.

Answer (score 1):

CSS cannot control this, other than hiding all of the links. You'd need to use JavaScript for this....or edit the PHP source.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit difficult to determin what you want to do but....

You can hide *all* links using the css

```
a {display: none};
```

Or hit a specific selector or class such as so you would only hide specific links...

```
a.wp-link {display: none};
```

You could also do something using javascript such as

(jQuery example)

```
$("a").attr("href", "#");
```

This would replace all link urls with a # or what ever you want - so you could also set a redirect.

Finally you could so somthing more sophisticated:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  alert('Site under development...check back soon.');
  return false;
});
```

That (untested) would show an alert if a link was clicked and prevent its default action.

Note all these seem very 'hacky' and if it is a short term fix while you are developing would be acceptable but if you are looking at a long term solution it seems like you need to have a more indepth look at your wordpress set up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
})
```